# How do I run multiple sh commands in a function in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Given the following Jenkinsfile:

```
@NonCPS
void touchFiles() {
    sh "touch foo"
    sh "touch bar"
}

node('general') {
    touchFiles()

    sh "ls"
}
```

I see the following in the console log on Jenkins:

```
Running on box35 in /internal/slave/build/workspace/1499786637.EXAMPLE_test-repo_test_jenkinsfile
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[1499786637.EXAMPLE_test-repo_test_jenkinsfile] Running shell script
+ touch foo
[Pipeline] sh
[1499786637.EXAMPLE_test-repo_test_jenkinsfile] Running shell script
+ ls
foo
```

Note that 'bar' has not been created.

Why does only the first `sh` run here? How can I factor out a series of `sh` calls in a Jenkinsfile?

(I know I could write `sh "touch foo; touch bar"` but in more complex Jenkinsfiles I sometimes need separate `sh` invocations.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer from @arifCee, you could do this:

```
@NonCPS
void touchFiles() {
    sh '''
    touch foo
    touch bar
    '''
}

node('general') {
    touchFiles()

    sh "ls"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one sh command and concatenate your arguments:

```
@NonCPS
void touchFiles() {
    sh "touch foo;" +
       "touch bar"
}

node('general') {
    touchFiles()

    sh "ls"
}
```

Comment: This is true, but sometimes I need to run separate `sh` commands.